# Check if there are any formulas in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of code that runs through my worksheets and highlights all cells with formulas in them. This part of the code works fine, however, if there are no cells with formulas in a worksheet, then the code crashes. What I want to do, is put an if statement in that will end the code if there are no formulas in the spreadsheet. I have tried to loop through the cells and check if there each cell has a formula but that crashes as well. So what I am looking to do is fix the if statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Highlighting Code**

```
'Apply yellow highlight to all formula cells.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each rng In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
Next rng
```

**Code with if statement**

```
'Apply yellow highlight to all formula cells.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

c = 0
For Each cell in ws.Cells
If cell.HasFormula = True Then
c= c + 1
End If
Next cell

If c > 0 Then
For Each rng In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
Next rng
Else MsgBox ("No formulas in this worksheet")
End If
```

Comment: FYI, not a VBA solution, but you can use conditional formatting to highlight formula cells as described here: http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/usertips/tip045.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use error handling in the code.

`On Error Resume Next` will continue execution on the next line without interrupting the script even when error occurs.
`On Error Goto 0` disables enabled error handler in the current procedure and resets it to Nothing.

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each cell In rng
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
Sub t()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    If ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count > 0 Then
        For Each rng In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        Next rng
    Else: MsgBox ("No formulas in this worksheet")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub subCheckForFormla()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim cel

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count > 0 Then
            If Not Err = 1004 Then
                For Each cel In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Cells
                    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                Next cel
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but in case someone needs it in the future the easiest way to check if there are any formulas on the sheet is to just use HasFormula.

HasFormula is True if all cells in the range contain formulas; False if none of the cells in the range contains a formula; null otherwise.

You cannot just check if HasFormula = False because the check returns null if HasFormula is null, so you need to check the other two cases (null OR True) for it to work.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
If IsNull(ws.UsedRange.HasFormula) Or ws.UsedRange.HasFormula Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```